# There are multiple runtime errors after compiling the react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, import, runtime

Runtime errors when I run the react app!

The app has compiled properly, but there are about eight issues that I'm not able to figure out. Kindly assist me how to solve it.

`src/components/app/index.js`  :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';

import AuthUserContext from '../Session';

import Navigation from '../Navigation';
import LandingPage from '../Landing';
import SignUpPage from '../SignUp';
import SignInPage from '../SignIn';
import PasswordForgetPage from '../PasswordForget';
import HomePage from '../Home';
import AccountPage from '../Account';
import AdminPage from '../Admin';

import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';


class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      authUser: null,
    };
  }

  // Firebase offers a listener function in order to get the authenticated user from Firebase.
  componentDidMount() {
    this.listner = this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged (
      authUser => {
        authUser
          ? this.setState({ authUser })
          : this.setState({ authUser: null });
      }
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.listner();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthUserContext.Provider value = {this.state.authUser}>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <div>
              <Navigation authUser={this.state.authUser} />
              <hr />
              <Routes>
                <Route exact path = {ROUTES.LANDING} component = {LandingPage} />
                <Route exact path = {ROUTES.SIGN_UP} component = {SignUpPage} />
                <Route exact path = {ROUTES.SIGN_IN} component = {SignInPage} />
                <Route exact path = {ROUTES.PASSWORD_FORGET} component = {PasswordForgetPage} />
                <Route exact path = {ROUTES.HOME} component = {HomePage} />
                <Route exact path = {ROUTES.ACCOUNT} component = {AccountPage} />
                <Route exact path = {ROUTES.ADMIN} component = {AdminPage} />
              </Routes>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </AuthUserContext.Provider>
    );
  }

}

export default withFirebase(App);
```

`src/index.js`  :

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import App from './components/App';
import Firebase from './components/Firebase';

import FirebaseContext from './components/Firebase/context';

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

It seems there is some issue with import and export statements but I am not able to figure out exactly what is wrong! If needed I'll upload other components also but please help me figure out the error in this.

These are the error screenshots (nothing is being rendered on the screen) -

[1st error screen on running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUUKm.jpg)

[2nd error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xVp8.jpg)

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Please check the end of the post, I've added the screenshots of the errors.